# how to Start Laravel App on shared hosting (Bluehost)

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, ssh, bluehost

I've deployed my Laravel app on Bluehost
by ssh I trying to run "npm run dev"

[here what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC4jK.png)

if the problem in versions, then how to update node by ssh

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but laravel is php framework and should be run by some kind of web server that supports php (e.g.: apache, nginx, or some other web server written in php), not run in node.js

Comment: thanks for replying, this host 100% supports PHP, I have 3 sites made with WordPress and they are working perfectly, 
what I meant in my question is the node_modules, I cant run npm commands on my host 
* note 
it works fine with the other WordPress websites